# Changing number of row's and column's with 2 dropdowns in PHP

Tags: php, html, variables, html-select

First of all I would like to say that I am very new to PHP so maybe it is a stupid question, but there we go:
I have a two dropdown select tags that have the following code in html and php:

```
     <select>
        <option value="default">---a---</option>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<+100; $i++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>

     <select>
        <option value="default">---b---</option>
        <?php for($j=1; $j<=100; $j++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php $j ?>"><?php echo $j ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>
```

Then I have a table with a row and a column (well at least that has to be changed I mean):

```
    <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Date</th>
                    <th>Temp</th>
                    <th>Nr a</th>
                    <th colspan="2">a 1</th>
                    <!--another th___nr a-->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan="3"> </td>
                    <th>something</th>
                    <th>else</th>
                    <!--another something else___nr a-->
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <?php
                            //echo date(DATE_RFC822);
                            echo date('jS\, F\, Y');
                        ?>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="temp" placeholder="temp" />
                    </td>
                    <th>b 1</th>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="something" placeholder="something" />
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="number" name="else" placeholder="else" />
                    </td>
                    <!--another td___nr a-->
                </tr>
                <!--another tr___nr b-->
            </table>
```

What I want to do is that with the first dropdown to control the number of a's (columns) and with the second dropdown the number of b's (rows).
Is this possible with PHP and if it is, how?

I was thinking of somehow to memorize the number we choose in the dropdown into a variable and with some for's to resolve it, but I don't really know how to do it, IF it is possible.

Thank you very much in advance for your time for helping me :)

Comment: You will need to make use of an ajax call. Make a php script that makes your entire table according to the 2 values in the dropbox. Than make an ajax call to that script. And pass the 2 values of the dropdownlist.

Comment: @ Dieter Thank you for the response. I am thinking about this solution tho I don't really wish to get into even more unknown things for me yet and probably it is a stupid question but is that ok for mobile applications as well, because this will have to run on a tablet? Thank you once again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP is a server side language, so you would have to post your (a) and (b) inputs back to the server then use PHP to construct the relevant data that could be used to generate the table you want on the page

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <!--put your select elements here-->
    <select name="columns"></select>
    <select name="rows"></select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Then in the top of the PHP file something like

```
<?php
    // using terniary operator here - you can google that
    // basically ensures the vars are set to 1 if there is no post from the form
    $columns = (isset($_POST['columns'])) ? $_POST['columns'] : 1;
    $rows = (isset($_POST['rows'])) ? $_POST['rows'] : 1;
?>
```

Then in your table

```
<table>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
        <tr>
            <?php foreach ($columns as $column):?>
            <td></td>
            <?php endforeach;?>
        </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

You could enhance this as Dieter suggested with Ajax, but for pure PHP you'll need something like this.

Its a very basic example though, and will need fleshing out to fulfil anything more than generating an empty HTML table with X columns and Y rows.

Edit: This is a completed file that should work. Just save the code below this line as test.php and try it out. Then you can amend it to do exactly what you need.
Sorry, I made a little mistake too, I forgot to convert the posted data into a range that could be used in a foreach loop.  That's corrected below

```
<?php
// test.php

    // using terniary operator here - you can google that
    // basically ensures the vars are set to 1 if there is no post from the form
    $c = (isset($_POST['columns'])) ? $_POST['columns'] : 1;
    $r = (isset($_POST['rows'])) ? $_POST['rows'] : 1;

    $columns = range(1, $c);
    $rows = range(1, $r);

?>


<form action="test.php" method="post">
    <!--put your select elements here-->
    <select name="rows">
        <option value="default">---a---</option>
        <?php for($i=1; $i<+100; $i++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $i ?>"><?php echo $i ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>

     <select name="columns">
        <option value="default">---b---</option>
        <?php for($j=1; $j<=100; $j++) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $j ?>"><?php echo $j ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
     </select>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>

<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column):?>
        <th>Temp Head</th>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
    <?php foreach ($rows as $row):?>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach ($columns as $column):?>
        <td>Temp Data</td>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </tr>
    <?php endforeach;?>
</table>
```

Comment: My code was an example of how to do it, not a final solution that could be copied/pasted into your file, sorry I didn't make that clear.

Comment: Hey there, first of all thank you for responding. I just tried and looked over the code you posted and I was getting these warnings/errors: _Undefined variable: rows in..._ and _Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..._ (due the first one i suppose). Then I realized that you are talking about a solution with 2 different files and so i did it like that and now I am getting the second error that says _Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in..._. Am doing something wrong? I have the form in the first PHP (don't ask me why PHP) and the rest in a second PHP. Any idea please? THX

Comment: Oh ok. Sorry. I am very new to it and it is a bit hard >.<

Comment: awwww Thank you very very much :D I owe you one :D I will check the code to understand it well. Thank you!!!

Comment: oh yes that was the problem then; the converting to the range